# How to make an object bounce with physics

Tags: animation, physics

i am trying to create an animation where a stretchy "i" bounces on a tnt switch...i thought of creating the bounce with just animation but know i have no idea on how to make the lever as in the picture react to it(move downwards as the "i" bounces)...all i need is pointers on how to do it any help will be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with rigid body physics using a generic spring constraint. You set up the constraint as an empty that controls the upper and lower bounds as well as the spriginess. I'll attach a blend file that gives an example of a ball falling onto a spring board that bounces up and down on a spring. It should serve as a guide for what you want to do.

[rigid body - spring plate.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Tlcrz9ZntGTEZaenB3bE5xMWs)

EDIT: In the example, I have an empty that points to the top and bottom plates of the spring board. The top plate is active and the bottom plate is passive. (The other parts are not rigid bodies so they could be removes with no consequence.)

[image]

The upper and lower bounds for the spring are set in the Limits fields for the empty (physics context window). In your case (like mine), you need to set values for the z axis, and leave the others at 0.0.

The springiness is set in the Springs fields for the empty. Again, you set the z axis and leave the others alone.

You should also toggle the Disable Collisions checkbox for the empty.

Comment: thanks a lot !! its exactly what i was looking for ill use your method

Comment: the link is to a road project blend not the spring blend and ive already marked it as correct i think :-)

Comment: Great! Glad to have been helpful! Please click on the button to accept this answer so I can relish in the points I'll get.

Comment: hang on, I'll give you the right link.

Comment: try this... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Tlcrz9ZntGTEZaenB3bE5xMWs

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an old thread, I was trying to bounce a ball on a plane. There is bounciness property on rigid body. Changing it to more than 0 on both the bodies, result in a bounce

Answer (score -1):

there is an excellent tutorial on youtube of how to animate a bouncing ball.
Its from a DVD series called humane rigging on youtube.

here is the tutorial for a [2D bouncing ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNOpqFsrCk4&list=PL3wFcRXImVPOQpi-wi7uriXBkykXVUntv&index=3)

and here is one for a [3D bouncing ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDrR0aMFhiU&list=PL3wFcRXImVPOQpi-wi7uriXBkykXVUntv&index=17)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does this answer. Please include some of the steps in the body of the answer itself.

Comment: oh yea, that makes sense

Comment: the video looks to complex for what im trying to do all im looking for is a spring like animation i thin ill go with Anthony's answer

Comment: I found it while reading the blender reference manual. He worked on the Big Buck Bunny project.